# Given an arbitrarily large file containing integers, return the largest N numbers, highest first

Tags: performance, algorithm, ruby, sorting, io

I've written a `top_n` program in Ruby, which does pretty much exactly what the title says, as part of a coding exercise. I'm trying to learn about how to sort efficiently (i.e. deciding the best sorting algorithm and implementing them or their variations), to manage memory efficiently, and know whether I'm using the right language/constructs/ideas to tackle a sorting problem.

What I'm looking for is advice on the algorithm and the code in general. I feel it can be done MUCH, MUCH better (i.e. I'm doing splits and casting to integers... my intuition tells me something could be better).

I'd really appreciate if someone gave me some pointers on how could I improve this little program. Thanks in advance.

```
require 'set'

class File
  def self.tail(path, n = 10)
    result = File.open(path, 'r') do |file|
      buffer_size = 512
      line_count = 0

      file.seek(0, IO::SEEK_END)

      offset = file.pos

      while line_count <= n && offset > 0
       to_read = if (offset - buffer_size) < 0
                   offset
                 else
                   buffer_size
                 end

       file.seek(offset - to_read)

       data = file.read(to_read)

       data.reverse.each_char do |c|
         if line_count > n
           offset += 1
           break
         end

         offset -= 1

         if c == "\n"
           line_count += 1
         end
       end
      end

      file.seek(offset)
      file.read
    end

    result
  end

  def each_chunk(chunk_size)
    yield read(chunk_size) until eof?
  end
end

def top_n(filename, n = 100)
  pre_sorted_chunks = Dir[".#{filename}_sorted_chunk_*"]

  if pre_sorted_chunks.empty?
    build_pre_sorted_chunks_for(filename)
  end

  top = SortedSet.new

  # This reference takes ±0.141 seconds.
  # pre_sorted_chunks.each do |file|
  #   top << `tail -n #{n} #{file}`.strip.split.map(&:to_i)
  # end

  # This takes ±0.130 seconds. A little better.
  tasks = pre_sorted_chunks.map do |chunk_file_path|
    Thread.new(chunk_file_path) do |file_path|
      top << File.tail(file_path, n).strip.split.map(&:to_i)
    end
  end

  tasks.each(&:join)

  top.max(n)
end

# Current impl. takes ±5m. A lot of time.
def build_pre_sorted_chunks_for(filename)
  File.open(filename) do |file|
    n = 0

    # Chunks of 500MB.
    file.each_chunk(1024 ** 2 * 500) do |chunk|
      numbers = chunk.split.map(&:to_i)

      sorted_set = SortedSet.new(numbers)
      sorted_set = sorted_set.to_a.join("\n")

      File.open(".#{filename}_sorted_chunk_#{n}", 'w') do |f|
        f.write(sorted_set)
      end

      n += 1
    end
  end
end

unless ARGV.empty?
  filename = ARGV[0]
  n = ARGV[1].to_i

  puts top_n(filename, n)
else
  puts "Please provide a filename and a N value to calculate the top N."
end
```

I've used this method to create a file with random numbers:

```
def generate_random_number_file(n = 15_000_000)
  require 'set'

  randoms = Set.new

  loop do
    randoms << rand(n)
    break if randoms.size >= n
  end

  File.open('randos.txt', 'w') do |file|
    random_list = randoms.to_a.join("\n")
    file.write(random_list)
  end
end
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you wrote your own File tail, instead of using the 'file-tail' gem? And wrote your own  benchmarking code instead of using the conventional Benchmark gem?

Comment: @MarkThomas No particular reason. I just wanted to stick to the core/standard library as much as I could. As for the benchmarking code... I definitely should've used the `benchmark` module. I'll re-run it and update the benchmarks. Thanks.

Comment: Since we're on Code Review, I must tell you that in the Ruby community it is considered wasteful and even foolish to 'stick to standard libraries' if there exists a gem which does what you want.

Comment: @MarkThomas Yes, I agree entirely. I would never try to reinvent the wheel just to accomplish something already solved efficiently. Unless I'm playing around, trying to learn how things work, which is what I'm doing here right now.

Comment: Is the output the largest `n` numbers or unique numbers? In other words is it OK if the top `n` are all the same 15_000_000?

Comment: @MarkThomas I think the largest N _unique_ numbers would be correct. If the 15-million-numbers file would have only 10 unique numbers, or even less, the output would be those N largest unique numbers.

Comment: So unless you are wedded to sort/tail it would seem much more efficient to just buffer the largest N numbers?

Comment: @NetMage Can you please clarify what do you mean with "just buffer the largest N numbers" and why it would be much more efficient? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Consider remembering the n largest numbers:

```
def top_n(filename, n = 100)
    require 'set'

    topn = SortedSet.new()

    File.foreach(filename) do |line|
        num = line.to_i
        if topn.length < n
            topn.add(num)
        elsif num > topn.first
            topn.delete(topn.first)
            topn.add(num)
        end
    end
    return topn.to_a
end
```

Comment: Thanks @NetMage. I wonder how can I stress-test this to see if it's an apt solution for a multi-hundred GB file.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if a TopNSet class might be of use here. I'm not sure how it would perform, but it seems like separating the reading of the values from the file, and getting the Top-N are different activities, and a TopNSet might be of value more widely.

I implemented it as:

```
class TopNSet
  def initialize(n)
    @n      = n
    @values = Set.new
  end

  def << number
    values << number
    values.delete(values.min) if values.size > n
    to_a
  end

  def to_a
    values.to_a
  end

  private

  attr_accessor :values, :n
end
```

... and hence ...

```
2.2.5 :021 >     t = TopNSet.new(3)
 => #<TopNSet:0x000001145cca28 @n=3, @values=#<Set: {}>> 
2.2.5 :022 >     t << 1
 => [1] 
2.2.5 :023 >     t << 2
 => [1, 2] 
2.2.5 :024 >     t << 3
 => [1, 2, 3] 
2.2.5 :025 >     t << 4
 => [2, 3, 4] 
2.2.5 :026 >     t << 4
 => [2, 3, 4] 
2.2.5 :027 >     t << 3
 => [2, 3, 4] 
2.2.5 :028 >     t << 7
 => [3, 4, 7] 
2.2.5 :029 >     t << 6
 => [4, 7, 6] 
2.2.5 :030 >     t << 1
 => [4, 7, 6]
```

Comment: I used a SortedSet instead of a Set on the theory that inserting a number in the proper position and retrieving the minimum would be more efficient than scanning the entire set for the minimum when a deletion is necessary.

Comment: @NetMage Sounds sensible -- benchmarking `Set` vs `SortedSet`  would be interesting.